# jQuery Animation Conditional w/a Callback Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, core-animation, conditional-statements

**EDIT BELLOW**

How do I code the #west animation call on the #contentBox animation when it completes?

Basically I have a toggle button that animates/changes a div's css and then to another div's css once/after the first animation completes; then reverses the next time the toggle is executed.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank-you.

The Conditional Statements:

```
$("#menuToggle").click(
    function() {

        var $west = $("#west");
        var $contentBox = $("#contentBox");

        $contentBox.animate({
                marginLeft : parseInt($contentBox
                        .css('marginLeft'), 10) == -320
                        ? $contentBox.outerWidth()
                        : -320
        });

        $west.animate({
            left : parseInt($west
                .css("left"), 10) == 0 
                ? -$west.outerWidth() 
                : 0
        });
   });
```

I went to the old fashoned way with out shorthanding the conditional statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-wrote the statement so it wasnt in shorthand and it works fine.

```
$("#menuToggle").click(

        function() {
            //var n = $("#west");
            var position = $("#west").offset();

            if (position.left == "0") {
                $("#west").animate({"left" : "-=300px"}, "slow")
                .animate({"width" : "1%"}, "fast", 
                    function() {
                    $("#contentBox").animate({"width" : "98%"}, "normal");
                });
            } else {
                $("#contentBox").animate({"width" : "70%"}, "normal", 
                    function() {
                    $("#west").animate({"width" : "30%"}, "fast")
                    .animate({"left" : "+=300px"}, "slow");
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass a callback function to the animate() method, which execuies once the animation is complete.

```
$("#menuToggle").click(
    function() {

        var $west = $("#west");
        var $contentBox = $("#contentBox");

        $contentBox.animate({
                marginLeft : parseInt($contentBox
                        .css('marginLeft'), 10) == -320
                        ? $contentBox.outerWidth()
                        : -320
        }, 5000, function() {
             //this is the callback part
            $west.animate({
                left : parseInt($west
                    .css("left"), 10) == 0 
                    ? -$west.outerWidth() 
                    : 0
            });
        });

   });
```

Comment: Thx. Thats what I thought but when the toggle is clicked only the callback runs then if the toggle is clicked again, they both run but out of sync.

Comment: @Andaero, Running async is not a good solution. Not its better to give a little breathing space to the animation effect to complete.

Comment: haw can I accomplish this? Thnx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The callback functionality should work in this case, but one thing to consider is if you've already animated to a 10x10 box (for example) and you ask jQuery to animate to the same 10x10 size - jQuery sees the animation as already completed. So in this case it would execute the callback right away. I'm guessing your if block for the animation there may need to be adjusted.

One thing you could do is add a 2 state check on your onClick event, something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/YAVk4/

I'd recommend adding/removing classes and checking for classes to keep your state of animation, but I made this quick and dirty XD.